# jQuery event not triggered

Tags: ajax, jquery

I've this piece of markup. This piece has been loaded through ajax and appended inside a div.

Content of file `user-bar.php`:

```
<div id="u-bar">
    <ul id="u-nav" class="nav">
        <li id="notifications-list" class="dropdown" data-time="" >
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="icon-comment"></i>
            Notifications
            <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
                <li><a href="#">Notification One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Notification two</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Show All Notifications</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="icon-user"></i>
            Profile
            <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">View Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="php/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've `scripts.js` file as below which is included in the `index.php` file as `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>`

```
$(function(){
    loadUserBar();

    $('#notifications-list').live('click', function(){
        console.log('Test');
        $('#notifications-list .icon-comment').removeClass('new');
    });
});

function loadUserBar(){
     $('#user-area').load('php/user-bar.php', function(){
         initBootstrapElems(); //Initializing All popover elements
     });    
}
```

`index.php` file has the `div#user-area` where the ajax returned markup is inserted.

After the whole page has been loaded, when I click on the list-item `#notifications-list`, nothing happens. But when I typed in `$('#notifications-list').click()` directly in the console, the log does appears and the `removeClass` does occur.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Did you put this jquery code on the callback of the ajax call?

Comment: No. The jquery code is in the main page. How do I put in the callback?

Comment: I put the jquery scripts in the ajax returned markup along with the `li` item here but still the same issue.

Comment: Please see me update below. You're using the same ID for all li tags. You should use a class instead or put the ID on the list (ol or ul tag). Hope this helps

Comment: Could you post the entire code (where you make the ajax call, where you insert the result, etc.)?

Comment: I'v updated the codes. The script is in the index.php file.

Comment: That seems to work: http://jsbin.com/ijiqec/edit#javascript,html,live (tested on Chrome). Is this problem happening on all browsers?

Comment: Problem on FF and Chrome. Have not tested in IE though. I'm using twitter bootstrap http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/. Could there be a chance of some conflict? I checked out the jsbin link you've shared. It's working fine there.

Comment: When you click the li, is there any error message at the console (Firebug or similar)?

Comment: No errors. It's like nothing has happened.

Comment: I found something out. I'm using this JS Twitter Bootstrap plugin at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns. If I remove it, it works fine. So there must be a conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, there's a conflict with dropdown bootstrap (simulated at http://jsbin.com/ijiqec/2/edit).

For some reason (don't ask me why) changing the use of **live** by **on** fixed the issue.
Use this piece of code:

`$('#notifications-list').on('click',...`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. But I had to put the js scripts in the `user-bar.php` file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the handler for click on the a tag event.

```
$('#notifications-list a').live('click', function(){ ... })
```

Update:
You can't use the same id for all li tags.
You need to change the li.#notifications-list to a class if you have that on each tag and then update the js:

```
$('.notifications-list a').live('click', function(){ ... })
```